# Does the AM-GM inequality not hold if there is a variable on the GM side?

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality

To find the minimum value of $x+\dfrac{1}{x}$, $(x>0)$ we can use the AM-GM inequality to say that $$\dfrac{x+\dfrac{1}{x}}{2}\geq \sqrt{x\cdot \dfrac{1}{x}}$$ or $$x+\dfrac{1}{x}\geq 2$$
The minimum value is when $x=\dfrac{1}{x}$ i.e. at $x=1$

If we take another function $4x^{3}+\dfrac{1}{x}$ then $$\dfrac{4x^{3}+\dfrac{1}{x}}{2}\geq \sqrt{4x^{3}\cdot \dfrac{1}{x}}$$ or $$4x^{3}+\dfrac{1}{x}\geq 4x$$ Here the minimum value should be $2\sqrt{2}$ at $4x^{3}=\dfrac{1}{x}$ i.e. at $x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ but the actual minimum value is at $x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4] {12}}$.
This is just a random example but I've noticed that if the variables don't cancel out on the GM side then the wrong minimum value is obtained. What am I doing wrong?
(Note: I am aware that there are better methods to find the minimum value. I am just wondering about this specific method.)

Comment: Check your math. You should get the same min value.

Answer (score 4):

Plotting the curves $4x^3+1/x$ and $4x$ might help you understand the issue. The AM-GM inequality always holds. The blue curve is above the red one, except in one point. But that point is not the minimum of the blue curve.

[image]

Comment: Sorry @JohnOmielan. It's just a typo in my text. The function plotted is indeed $4x^3+1/x$

Answer (score 0):

Use AM-GM like this:

$$4x^3+\frac{1}{x}=4x^3+\frac{1}{3x}+\frac{1}{3x}+\frac{1}{3x}\geq4(4x^3\cdot \frac{1}{3x}\cdot \frac{1}{3x}\cdot \frac{1}{3x})^\frac{1}{4}=4(\frac{4}{27})^\frac{1}{4}$$